# Telegram bots: want to use php sleep() function in webhook

Tags: php, webhooks, telegram-bot

**What I have**

a telegram bot (backend PHP) with `webhook` set. It have several commands I am entertaining.

**What I want to do**

As soon as user enters a specific command in telegram chat to my bot,
 I am sending him message that I will message him after 15 mins . Now I
 want to send him some message after 15 mins.

**What I have done**

I tried using `sleep()`of php to pause `webhook` execution for 15 mins and then send message. But after few seconds though user have not sent any message webhook recieved a message with text field containing **5\u2063** and php script got reloaded.

**Is there any way I can do what I am trying to do?**

Comment: show your code if you want people to help

Comment: its 2k lines of code? forget the code, any other way to do what I want? like savin g time and triggering send message function after 15 mins? Any way?

Answer (score 1):

you can insert a query in db
time_end = (time()+(60*15));
and in another php file that set it for a cron job(every one min) check if time() >= $row['time_end']
do somthing